# Separate volume level for speaker-phone mode?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, speakerphone, volume-control

My phone (a Samsung Vibrant, aka T-Mobile's variant of the Galaxy S) has a single volume level for both the speaker-phone and normal modes.  I like to have it up high if I'm using speaker-phone mode and less deafening when I'm holding the handset to my ear.  This causes some problems when I use a different mode from the previous call.

Is there any way that I can have a separate volume level for the two modes of operation?

Answer (score 3):

Boy, separate volume controls for the speaker and earpiece would be useful, wouldn't they?

You can probably do what you want with [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/). It lets you control all kinds of settings on the phone based on events. ([Some ideas from Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5601133/push-your-automated-android-to-awesome-heights-with-these-tasker-setups).)

Comment: +1 for Tasker.  I brief look at the options avaliable make it seem like it can be done.

Comment: I've looked at Tasker and I'm not sure I can do it: ppeakerphone control is available as a `Task`, but I think I would need a speakerphone `State` to trigger a change in the volume.  It's a cool app, though. +1